# jQuery notification sound using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file that returns new items from db and using ajax, i update a div with number of new items.

In order to make it look a bit like facebook, i have inside a `setInterval(3000 ms)` the ajax call.All ok here.
Now i want to play a sound when new items comes up.

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "script.php",
    data: { action : somedata },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      if(html > 0) {
        // update div
      }else{
        //do nothing
      }
    }
})`
```

I googled how to play a sound in jQuery, and i got a working solution:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'notification.ogg');
audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');

$.get();
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
audioElement.play();
}, true);
```

If i put the previous code here:

```
if(html > 0) {
here
}
```

the sound is played, but there's a problem. It's played every 3000ms. I don't want this. I want to play it only when a new item comes up in the db, and not every time the ajax call is made.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: A better conditional statement that actually checks if a new item is added, and not if the `html > 0`. We're not mind-readers, so we have no idea how to help you. What does the returned data look like? How do you discern when something new is available or not?

Comment: In my db , i have a table called `notifications` which has a column named `read`, so, in my php script, i check only for items where read = no.

Comment: So what do you return when there's items? An object, a number, an HTML string, a json encoded array...etc. When there's no items, what do you return? false? 0? a message?

Comment: I return the number of unread notifications.

Comment: And what do you return when there are no notifications? because that function is always firing `true`, that's why the sound plays every 3 seconds. Furthermore, you can add a new event listener to the `ended` method (just like you did with load)` and call `audioElement.stop();` in that just to make sure.

Comment: When there are no new notifications, i simply return `0`, so that condition will not be true.